# How to use multiple dashboard in a single HTML page (Google Visualization)?

Tags: html, google-visualization

I am new to Google Visualization and JS script. And seeking little help on 
"how to use multiple dashboard in a single HTML page to display two different types of data".

I found that a single dashboard can only be attached to a particular type of data (like Type 1 can only be used with TimeLine Chart). And we can not use LineChart with dashboard attached to TimeLine Chart.

I have two types of data and want to display them with TimeLine Chart and LineChart in a single page.

**Type 1**: TimeLine data with following details:

```
['Name', 'Task', 'Msg', 'Startime', 'Endtime']
```

**Type 2**: LineChart Data with following details:

```
[number,  data_for_line1, data_for_line2, data_for_line3]
```

How to display both kind of data in a single HTML page using Google Visualization
TimeLine and LineChart ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

drawing multiple dashboards isn't much different from drawing one

for a quick demonstration, the following snippet was pulled from the other question posted recently

**first**, a couple modifications were made to the original code

1. `loader.js` was included *twice*, once in the `<head>` and another in the `<body>`
   be sure to only include this once, since a `callback` is available, placing in the `<head>` is fine
2. As for the `callback`, it was also declared *twice*
   once in the `load` statement, and again using `setOnLoadCallback`
   only need one of these, lose `setOnLoadCallback`

back to drawing multiple dashboards, see following working snippet...

the `callback` has been modified to call two functions
`drawVisualization` and `drawVisualization2`

basically copied the draw function and the dom elements, which were each given a unique `id`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawVisualization();
    drawVisualization2();
  },
  packages:['controls', 'table', 'timeline']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
  document.getElementById('dashboard'));

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'control',
      'options': {
          'hAxis':{'slantedText':'true','direction':'1','format': { 'pattern':'0' }},
          'hAxis.gridlines.color':'#ccc',
          'hAxis': {
              gridlines: {
                  color: 'transparent'
              }
          },
          'filterColumnLabel': 'Start',
          'ui': {
              'format': {
                  'pattern': 0
              },
              'labelStacking': 'horizontal'
          }
      }
  });

  var stringControl = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'StringFilter',
      'containerId': 'stringControl',
      'options': {
          'hAxis':{'slantedText':'true','direction':'1','format': { 'pattern':'0' }},
          'hAxis.gridlines.color':'#ccc',
          'hAxis': {
              gridlines: {
                  color: 'transparent'
              }
          },
          'filterColumnLabel': 'P',
          'matchType': 'any',
          'ui': {
              'format': {
                  'pattern': 0
              },
              'labelStacking': 'horizontal'
          }
      }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Timeline',
      containerId: 'chart',
      options: {
          'width': 1200,
          'height': 600,
          'timeline': {
              'rowLabelStyle': {
                  'fontName': 'Helvetica',
                  'fontSize': 16,
                  'color': '#603913',
              },
              'barLabelStyle': {
                  'fontName': 'Garamond',
                  'fontSize': 9
              }
          },
          'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'format': { 'pattern':'####','fractionDigits':'0','groupingSymbol':'','showRangeValues':true },
          backgroundColor: '#ffd',
          hAxis: {
              minValue: 0,
          },
          'chartArea': {
              width: '100%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
              height: '100%'
          },
      },
      'view': {
              'columns': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
      },
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'table'
  });

  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
// ###### Data Should be placed here ######
      ['P', 'Task', 'Msg', 'Start', 'End'],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,1      ,2],
      ['P2_1'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,101    ,102],
      ['P2_1'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0  asdjam  adasd'                                                        ,102    ,107],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,103    ,104],
      ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 2 g 1 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,105    ,106],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,11     ,12],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,111    ,113],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,114    ,125],
      ['P3_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0  asdhas  asdhasd'                                                      ,116    ,117],
      ['P3_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,117    ,122],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,118    ,119],
      ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 3 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,120    ,121],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,126    ,128],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,129    ,140],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,13     ,14],
      ['P4_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,131    ,132],
      ['P4_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,132    ,137],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,133    ,134],
      ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 4 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,135    ,136],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,15     ,17],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,18     ,20],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,21     ,22],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,23     ,24],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,25     ,27],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,28     ,29],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,3      ,4],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,30     ,31],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,32     ,34],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,35     ,36],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,37     ,38],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,39     ,41],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,42     ,43],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,44     ,45],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,46     ,48],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,49     ,51],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,5      ,6],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,52     ,54],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,55     ,57],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,58     ,69],
      ['P0_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,60     ,61],
      ['P0_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,61     ,66],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,62     ,63],
      ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 0 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,64     ,65],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,7      ,8],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,70     ,72],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,73     ,95],
      ['P1_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,76     ,79],
      ['P2_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 1 new_index 0'                                                                       ,77     ,78],
      ['P2_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 1 new_index 0'                                                                       ,78     ,91],
      ['P1_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,79     ,88],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,80     ,81],
      ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 1 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 wt_done'                                              ,82     ,83],
      ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 1 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 wt_done'                                              ,84     ,85],
      ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 1 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,86     ,87],
      ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 2 g 0 my_index 1 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,89     ,90],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,9      ,10],
      ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,96     ,98],
      ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,99     ,110],
// ###### End of data ######
  ]);

  data.setColumnProperty(2, 'role', 'tooltip');
  data.setColumnProperty(2, 'html', true);

// ###### Bind Table ######
  dashboard.bind([control, stringControl], [chart]);
// ###### Bind Table End here ######

  dashboard.draw(data);
}

function drawVisualization2() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
  document.getElementById('dashboard2'));

  var stringControl = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'StringFilter',
      'containerId': 'stringControl2',
      'options': {
          'hAxis':{'slantedText':'true','direction':'1','format': { 'pattern':'0' }},
          'hAxis.gridlines.color':'#ccc',
          'hAxis': {
              gridlines: {
                  color: 'transparent'
              }
          },
          'filterColumnLabel': 'Month',
          'matchType': 'any',
          'ui': {
              'format': {
                  'pattern': 0
              },
              'labelStacking': 'horizontal'
          }
      }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      containerId: 'chart2',
      options: {
          'width': 1200,
          'height': 600,
          'timeline': {
              'rowLabelStyle': {
                  'fontName': 'Helvetica',
                  'fontSize': 16,
                  'color': '#603913',
              },
              'barLabelStyle': {
                  'fontName': 'Garamond',
                  'fontSize': 9
              }
          },
          'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'format': { 'pattern':'####','fractionDigits':'0','groupingSymbol':'','showRangeValues':true },
          backgroundColor: '#ffd',
          hAxis: {
              minValue: 0,
          },
          'chartArea': {
              width: '100%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
              height: '100%'
          },
      },
  });

  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'A', 'B'],
    ['Aug', 3754, 3900],
    ['Sep', 1900, 1500],
    ['Oct', 2000, 1200],
    ['Nov', 1700, 2050],
    ['Dec', 2400, 2680]
  ]);

  dashboard.bind([stringControl], [chart]);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;">
  <div class="center" id="control" style="margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid green;"> </div > <br>
  <div class="center" id="stringControl" style="margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid green;"> </div > <br> <br>
  <div id="chart" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 200px; bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 200px; "></div>
  <div id="table"></div>
</div>
<div id="dashboard2" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;">
  <div class="center" id="stringControl2" style="margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid green;"> </div > <br> <br>
  <div id="chart2" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 200px; bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 200px; "></div>
</div>
```